# MySQL not enabling adaptive flushing as per innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

I'm trying to tune up InnoDB buffer pool flush settings in MySQL. `innodb_adaptive_flushing` is OFF. Log file size is set to 4GB with 2 log files. So, max log file size would be 8GB. `innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm` is set to 40%.

Quoting [MySQL official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm) -

```
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm

Defines the low water mark representing percentage of redo log capacity at which adaptive flushing is enabled. For more information, see Section 14.8.3.5, “Configuring Buffer Pool Flushing”.

When that threshold is crossed, adaptive flushing is enabled, even if the innodb_adaptive_flushing variable is disabled.
```

With above settings, max checkpoint age would be 5.67GB, so MySQL should enable adaptive flushing when log size reaches 3.402GB (i.e. `5.67GB * 0.6`). Uncheckpointed bytes has already reached 4.45GB, so why MySQL isn't enabling adaptive flushing at this point ? What could be the possible reasons for the same ?

Graphs representing those metrics --

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
MySQL version -

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

To wrap up, all the related settings related to buffer pool flushing which one may be interested in --

```
innodb_adaptive_flushing - OFF
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm - 40
innodb_io_capacity - 1500
innodb_io_capacity_max - 5120
Max SSD disk IOPS from tests - 6000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct - 75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm - 40
innodb_lru_scan_depth - 250
```

#### Edit 1 -

More variables for reference.

```
innodb_log_file_size - 4GB
innodb_log_files_in_group - 2
innodb_buffer_pool_size - 10GB
```

Here's some context which could be unrelated to the actual issue but I'm adding it here in case it answers any question.

In my MySQL setup, with `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm - 40` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size - 10GB`, dirty page size in the buffer pool should be around 4GB. But it wasn't rising more than 1GB. That means there was some kind of dirty page flushing happening due to which it couldn't make till 4GB.

I think page flushing can primarily happen due to two reason.

1. InnoDB max dirty pages percentage increases more than innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm
2. Adaptive flushing algorithm feels that with current rate of writes to log file and current flushing rate, redo log files would fill up fast. So, it increases the flushing rate. If it increases the flushing rate, there could be performance degradation, page_cleaner issues, larger disk I/O happening.

We can very easily rule out (1) because as I mentioned earlier, it wasn't rising more than 1GB. So, I would guess it was due to adapative flushing. (MySQL doesn't provide any stats related to that).

To confirm my above hypothesis, I went on disabling the adaptive flushing so that it would only get enabled when `innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm` is hit but it didn't and here I come to StackOverflow whining about my issue.

Comment: What's the value of `innodb_log_file_size`?

Comment: @RickJames 10GB.

Comment: Isn't it a percent of that 10GB, not the buffer_pool?  By the way, `innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm` is almost never mentioned in questions and never (in my experience until now) changed from the default.  What do you expect the benefit to be?

Comment: Ah sorry @RickJames, seems like I misread. 10GB is the buffer_pool size. 

innodb_log_file_size is 4GB with innodb_log_files_in_group = 2.

And about configuring `innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm `, dirty page memory in my case weren't rising above 1.2 GB whereas according to `max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm` setting, they could go around 4GB. So, that means there's some kind of flushing happening from the buffer pool.

Comment: If it's not caused due to `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm`, then why did it happen ? I would say, adapative flushing. That's why I wanted to turn off the adaptive flushing and in case `max checkpoint age` touches high enough value, I would prefer enabling adaptive flushing using `innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm`. Otherwise it can cause a state when MySQL foreground threads would block and wait for background flushing threads to flush up log files which means down time.

Comment: "Log file size is set to 4GB with 2 log files." versus "10GB" ??

Comment: Please back up to the beginning of the story.  We entered after you decided that adaptive flushing was causing trouble. -- What trouble?

Comment: Yes, log file size is set to 4GB with 2 log files i.e. total max log file size is 8 GB. When I commented "10GB", I misread your comment. 10GB is buffer pool size.

Comment: The reason I disabled adaptive flushing is, I saw MySQL flushing dirty pages even when the amount of dirty pages didn't touch `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm` water mark. That means flushing was happening due to "adaptive flushing". That's the reason I disabled adaptive flushing to experiment things out but experienced above issue which posted as SO question i.e. `MySQL not enabling adaptive flushing as per innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm`.

Comment: @RickJames I have added new section in the above question to provide you whole background story.

Comment: Consider writing a bug at bugs.mysql.com .